# Why use separate load methods instead of the constructor?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, opentk

OpenTK has a separate Load() method it calls when the game has to load. XNA and MonoGame take it another step further and have the constructor, Initialize and LoadContent. All this seems to do for me as the programmer using the framework is be confused when I'm supposed to load something in and that I can't be 100% sure that a class is initialized when it's constructed. For what reason is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a reason that XNA has the constructor, Initialize, and LoadContent(). When you create a new game, such as in

```
static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (Game1 game = new Game1())
            {
                game.Run();
            }
        }
    }
```

Game1's constructor is called and takes care of pre-initialize tasks, such as

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
Components.Add(new gamecomponent());
```

and setting up the class's properties. You can use the constructor like to normally would. After the constructor is called, the `Game.Run()` method is called. This will start the game and call the initialize method. So in the above `Program`, once `game.Run()` is called, several things happen. First, `Game1`'s Initialize method is called. This method usually looks something like:

```
protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // now that the GraphicsDevice has been created, we can create the projection matrix.
        projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
            MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1f, 10000);

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

As you may notice, the `projectionMatrix` for this game is created in this method (not the constructor) because the graphicsDevice has been initialized once `Game.Run()` is called. After the Initialize method completes pre-game tasks `Base.Initialize()` is called, which does two things. First, any `GameComponents` you have added to the game are enumerated through and initialized. Second, LoadContent() is called once everything is initialized, both in the game and the gamecomponents, and the graphicsdevice is ready.

Now, you might wonder why `LoadContent()` isn't part of the initialize method. Well, I believe the main reason for this is so that you can reload the content if needed, "such as when the DeviceReset event occurs", or if you need to reset things like model mesh bones.

So in summary, the constructor creates the class and its properties like it normally would, then once the `Initialize` method it called, the game starts running after all the `GameComponents` have been initialized and the Content is loaded.

Comment: For what reason is the GraphicsDevice not initialized in the constructor?

Comment: Calling `Game.Run()` Creates and Initializes the `GraphicsDevice`. I suppose the reason it's not initialized in the constructor is so that you don't create multiple `graphicsdevice`s; `Game.Run()` is only called once. (For instance, if you had multiple screens, and initialized the graphicsdevice in the first screen, if you created and navigated back to the startup screen, you'd have another `GraphicsDevice`.)

Answer (score 1):

The architecture of an XNA game (or any other game engine/framework) is a little more complicated than a simple class architecture. Each method has it's own responsibility, and each one is being called on entirely different stages of the game.

First off, the constructor is being class by initializing a new instance of the game, just like any other class, inside the constructor the game host, platform and component managers are being initialized. After the constructor had finished no method is being called, (neither `Initialize` as you might expect).

Then to start the `Game Loop` you call the `Run` method, this method sets up the `GraphicsDevice`, `GameTime` and the `Game Loop` mechanisms. only then the `Initialize` method is being called. a few steps before the game starts running. Then `BeginRun` is being called, the first `Update` is firing and only then the game is 'officially' running.

Now the part that is missing is the `LoadContent`. `LoadContent` is the most "unforgiving" of the three - while you may use `Initialize` instead of the `Constructor` freely and the other way around, you may not use the `Constructor` nor `Initialize` instead of `LoadContent`, the reason is that `LoadContent` is being called by an `Event` which is firing by the `GraphicsDevice`, only when the `GraphicsDevice` is ready for use you can start loading content, the reason is that many Resources(`Content`) are being stored inside the Graphics Processing Unit (GPU) memory (Textures, Shaders, etc.) so you cannot load that kind of content until you have access the GPU memory via the `GraphicsDevice`.

To wrap things up:

- The constructor is being used to initialize everything that needs to be ready before the game starts running, (Services, Content Managers, etc.).
- The `Initialize` method is being used to initialize everything that is being used only when the game is running (Game Components for example).
- The `LoadContent` is being used to load any kind of content (usually via the `ContentManager`).